# Moving from ClearCase to Git

Tags: git, workflow, clearcase

I'm coming from a ClearCase background where we (simply speaking) had a workflow made up of three steps where the leftmost trunk was unstable, middle trunk is Quality Assurance and the rightmost was stable. i.e.)

```
A  A  A
|  |  |
B  C  |
| /|  |
C  |  E
|  | /  
D  E
| /
E
```

As you can see the stable trunk contains only the versions that have been qualified. I'm having problems replicating this workflow in Git as versions B, C and D are also pushed into the QA trunk and subsequently the stable trunk. In my eyes this defeats the purpose of a "clean" trunk containing only stable versions.

Now there's obviously fundamental differences between Git and ClearCase which I'm sure explains why I'm having trouble using my previous conceptions to specify a workflow.

I've been trying to wrap my head around these new SCM tools (I've looked at Mercurial too) for a couple of days now and **could really use some pointers on how to proceed**. We're developing on Mac and Windows PCs and the vast majority of the teams prefer GUI tools compared to command line.

Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you can read this [comparison between ClearCase and Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/645008/what-are-the-basic-clearcase-concepts-every-developer-should-know/645771#645771)

As explained in [Middle-ground between submodules and branches?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/932586/middle-ground-between-submodules-and-branches/932868#932868), the one concept which is likely to trick you when coming from ClearCase is the notion of composition (configuration inheritance): see [Flexible vs static branching (GIT vs Clearcase/Accurev)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/763099/flexible-vs-static-branching-git-vs-clearcase-accurev/764219#764219).

ClearCase works file by file (or activity by activity, each activity being a group of files).
Git works blob delta by blob delta (each blob representing a *content*: if two files have the same content, only one "blob" will be stored)

That means what you are trying to do in ClearCase through branch/streams and activities (if you are using UCM), will more likely be achieved through:

- commit reordering (rebase --interactive, which is the "git" way, and not recommended in mercurial)
- and/or **publication** (which is an [orthogonal dimension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2563836/sell-me-distributed-revision-control/2563917#2563917) to branching, specific to DVCS)

**reordering + merge** (only for commits not yet "published", ie not pushed):
You are reordering the modifications deltas applied to your code, in order to merge only what you want.

```
trunk => trunk'  QA => QA'  stable
  A        B'    
  |        |  
  B        D'
  |        |  
  C        A'----A'    C''
  |        |     |     |
  D        C'    C'    A''--  A''  (--: merge to branch)
  |        |     |     |      |
  E        E     E     E      E
```

- **reordering  + publication** (push):

You can also represent each code promotion by a git repo of its own.
Once the commits are in the proper order, you push the relevant branches to a QA repo, or a stable repo.

---

The reordering (history rewriting) is:

- [not encouraged in Mercurial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504409/is-it-worth-the-effort-to-create-pretty-revision-history-in-a-dvcs/510123#510123), while being [technically possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3178291/how-does-mercurial-work-with-many-developers)
- problematic when a developer pull a branch someone else has rebased (reordered): see the [RECOVERING FROM UPSTREAM REBASE](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#_recovering_from_upstream_rebase) section of the [`git rebase`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) man page.

See also:

- [A successful Git branching model](http://nvie.com/git-model)
- [Using Mercurial in a Large Organization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2479274/using-mercurial-in-a-large-organization/2479317#2479317)

Comment: Thank you. Being used to ClearCase these alternative tools are a bit overwhelming at first. Hopefully they'll be second nature in due time. :-)

Comment: @MdaG: you are welcome ;) For using both CVCS (Centralized VCS) and DVCS for quite some time, I find important to get the difference between the two. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2704996/describe-your-workflow-of-using-version-control-vcs-or-dvcs