# Migration from UCM ClearCase to GIT

Tags: git, migration, history, clearcase

I am studying migrating from UCM ClearCase to GIT. The initial intention is to migrate all cc branches with their respective history.

A similar experience, best practices, any tips or suggestions will be of great help.

Answer (score 1):

The biggest advice is in the UCM component to Git repository reorganization.

The migration is often a good opportunity to split (too) large UCM component into leaner Git repo.
Since Git is *distributed*, you need to keep in mind you will be cloning the *full* history around, so making that reorganization is important.

The other advice is to *not* import *all* the history, but to limit the import to the last significant baselines. (And keep ClearCase in read-only for archive)

you can find other advices in "[Moving from ClearCase to Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3510682/moving-from-clearcase-to-git/3511249#3511249)", more centered around the workflow of merges and branches organization.

---

In term of tool: I haven't found one.

I use:

- a dynamic view for rebasing to thee (full) baseline I want to export
- a snapshot view I update once the rebase is done in the dynamic view.
- a git repo working tree which I empty completely before copying the view snap content into it
- a git repo directory (`.git`) separate
- git commands with `--work-tree` referencing the updated working tree.

And I iterate for the few baselines I need to export from ClearCase/import into git.

Comment: Thanks VonC, The reorganization, and limited migration are to be considered. But I wonder, if you have came across any tool that might help doing the job ... I was not lucky googling that :)

Comment: @mohamedhaseeb no tool that I know of. I have edited the answer to address the methodology.