# How to migrate Clearcase UCM/Base VOBs to Git(Stash) with full history?

Tags: git, svn, clearcase, clearcase-ucm

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13759478/migration-from-ucm-clearcase-to-git),I am able to get only the repository stucture without history (manual migration), my primary requirement is to migrate **with history**.

I have an approach to migrate to Git with history Via Subversion, I dont want to use SVN as a mediator.

Is there any way to migrate using Script (irrespective of the languages) and if its available please help me where should I use it.

I require all the baselines/labels, branches with full history to Git.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

The history in [ClearCase is file-based, not repository (commit) based](https://stackoverflow.com/a/645771/6309).
Even with UCM activities, it isn't easy to go through each activity to import the repo at that state.
Only a [full baseline would be like an SVN revision or a Git commit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21160387/6309).

The best you can do is try and import each baseline, but that wouldn't import all the rebase and delivers between streams.

In short, I never saw a comprehensive script able to export the full history of a ClearCase Vob, which is why [I always settled on a partial import of a few baselines only](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26967852/6309).

Plus, in my case, I had vobs way too big to be a Git repo, and I had some binaries elements which would have to be excluded during the export anyway.

Comment: I did all the possible google search, i didnt get any solution hence I posted my query here. Please find [this script](https://github.com/charleso/git-cc) @VonC,i'm facing some errors,i don't know where to apply, that python script. Do you have any idea?

Comment: @CCUSER I mentioned git-cc here (http://stackoverflow.com/a/2342164/6309). His creator mentioned git-cc limitation (http://stackoverflow.com/a/2480512/6309), as replicating only one stream.

Comment: can you tell me@VonC where should i apply that python script to get history of atleast single stream