# How to migrate from IBM Clearcase to Visual Studio Team Services

Tags: git, tfs, azure-devops, clearcase, version-control-migration

We are considering moving from ClearCase to VSTS. The projects are fairly large and developed in various languages such as java, .NET, Cobol, Scripts, Database jobs, Cognos etc.

We need to migrate complete code history as well.

I am curious if there is someone that has done similar migration and provide some guidance on following points:

•Are tools available for ClearCase to Team Services migration?

•What are the prerequisites for such migration?

•Will VSTS be able to handle such a large project?

I am able to find enough documentation around how to migrate clearcase to TFS but don't know will that be sufficient for VSTS as well. Also what I understood from VSTS 2018 documentation, Git code can be completely migrated along with history to VSTS but not TFS code.

So I it will be really helpful if someone can guide me how to approach this migration.

Comment: Are you using Git repo within VSTS?

Comment: Hi Von, yes I need to use Git repo within VSTS. I have got few resources to migrate from Clearcase to git/ bitbucket and Clearcase to TFS but not sure about clearcase to VSTS. It will be great help if you can provide some pointers around it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then it is about migrating a ClearCase repository to Git, a [topic I touched on before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26967852/6309).

The main point is:

- don't try to migrate the all history: keep ClearCase around for archive/exploration of past history
- don't try to cram a all ClearCase Vob necessarily into *one* Git repository, and pay attention to your `.gitignore`: Git won't do well will many binary files that may have been stored into ClearCase.

The migration also depends on your ClearCase usage: base ClearCase or **[UCM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13759721/6309)**: in the latter case, components are more naturally migrated to their respective Git repository, with the last main baselines as content to import.